# Does SparkSQL support like type

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Does SparkSQL support like type query, I am looking for the equivalence like:

`select * from table where name like '%Bush'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does, you can execute such a query with regular SQL. For example:

```
val nadf = sqlContext.createDataFrame( Seq(
          ( "Alice", 10),
          ( "Alice", 20),
          ( "Bob", 10),
          ( "Bobo", 20)
          )).toDF("name", "age")
nadf.registerTempTable("nadf")
```

produces results like:

```
scala> sqlContext.sql("""select * from nadf where name like "%Bob"""").show()
+----+---+
|name|age|
+----+---+
| Bob| 10|
+----+---+


scala> sqlContext.sql("""select * from nadf where name like "%Bob%"""").show()
+----+---+
|name|age|
+----+---+
| Bob| 10|
|Bobo| 20|
+----+---+
```